# SQLPLUS - Calculating GPA for each student in, given their grade on each course, total credit hours, and credit hours for each course

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have these tables (some information removed as it isn't relevant to my question)

- course(course_id, credits)
- student(student_id, total_credits)
- takes(course_id, student_id, grade)
- grade_point(grade, points)

and I need to find the gpa for each student. It's the weighted gpa, which means the formula would be

sum(points * course.credits) / total_credits

Currently I'm struggling with how to tell SQL to calculate this for every student. The query I wrote is this:

```
SELECT student.student_id, (sum(grade_point.points * course.credits) / 
       student.total_credits) AS GPA
FROM   student, course, takes, grade_point
WHERE  grade_point.grade = takes.grade
AND    takes.course_id = course.course_id
AND    student.student_id = takes.student_id;
```

But as expected, I get the error about needing a `GROUP BY`. I know there needs to be a GROUP BY if I use an aggregate function but I'm not sure what to group this by.

I read that you would have to add the `SELECT` expression that isn't in the aggregate function to the `GROUP BY`, but if I do that I get a `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

I would like to avoid using PL/SQL as I'm not familiar with that yet. Also, because this is a homework problem I'd prefer hints over the actual solution. Thanks!

Comment: I hope that you do not mind my commenting here to help you with [this post you just unhappily deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407580/finding-candidate-keys-given-functional-dependencies-that-are-not-the-canonical).--I don't understand what you think is unreasonable in responses to it, we pointed out typos that stop us from answering it & I explained that you seem to be expecting us to redo all your work when we could check it, etc. Why don't you just fix the typos, show your work & explain about exactly where you got stuck? We would like to help you.

Comment: Oh I suppose you are offended by my comments re "I think it's". Look--I am seriously just trying to help you improve your problem solving by pointing out a common unhelpful & impeding habit of thought/writing. I will find a better way to comunicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an *aggregate* SQL query, where results are grouped by student. You need to indicate that to Oracle, by adding a `GROUP BY` clause to the query :

```
SELECT 
    s.student_id, 
    (SUM(gp.points * c.credits) / s.total_credits) AS GPA
FROM 
    student
    INNER JOIN takes t ON s.student_id = t.student_id
    INNER JOIN course c ON t.course_id = c.course_id
    INNER JOIN grade_point gp ON gp.grade = t.grade
GROUP BY s.student_id, s.total_credits
```

Another good SQL practice is to use explicit `JOIN`s instead of implicit syntax (ie table names separate by a comma in the `FROM` clause and joining conditions in the `WHERE` clause). I modified your query this way.

It is also a good idea to use table aliases : it makes the query more readable, and generally avoids name clashes.

Comment: I was under the assumption that table aliases are not allowed in sqlplus.

Comment: Also, this gives me an error, the same one that I mentioned in my question: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` It points at `s.total_credits`

Comment: @pinklemonade : sorry, I forgot to add that column to the `GROUP BY` clause, just updated my answer. PS : seems like are understanding the `GROUP BY` logic now  !

Comment: Ah! Why do you also have to group by the credits? I'm not sure I understand that. Is it because although it is a part of the GPA attribute it isn't part of the aggregate function?

Comment: Exactly. Every column that is in the SELECT clause and that is not part of an aggregate function (SUM() or else) must appear in the GROUP BY clause.